# How to eliminate warning for passing multidimensional array as const multidimensional array?

Tags: c, arrays, constants

given the following code:

```
/* signatures */
int getParams(char params[MAX_PARAM_LEN][MAX_LINE_LEN]);
int getVersion(const char params[MAX_PARAM_LEN][MAX_LINE_LEN],
               const char* tagName );
/* initializing */
char params[MAX_PARAM_LEN][MAX_LINE_LEN] = {};

/* getting parameters */
paramCount = getParams(params); /* OK, params match with getParams signature */

/* processing the params array */
i = getVersion(params, "version"); /* warning: passing arg 1 of `getVersion' from incompatible pointer type */
```

I see that the constness is the problem, but I don't know why or how to avoid it. What I want is a function which can't modify the `params` anymore. Any advice is welcome(besides disabling this warning or deleting const in the processing function).

Thanks:
Visko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't eliminate these warnings in C without making an explicit cast to the proper type. Without a typedef this is going to look ugly though

```
i = getVersion((const char (*)[MAX_LINE_LEN]) params, "version")
```

This is a strange quirk specific to C language. In C++ this issue was fixed.

BTW, the `{}` initializer is illegal in C. How did you manage to get *that* to compile?

Comment: Thanks, with a
#define param_const_t const char (*)[MAX_LINE_LEN]
it's not that ugly. It's just non-sense to me why this strictness increasing "casting" causes warning.

Comment: I've been using the {} initializer for a while. I'm using gcc, but I had no problem with visual studio's compiler. Now that you mentioned, I tried with cadul compiler (which is so ANSI standard that it wouldn't accept // as comment) and it fails. Another non-sense thing...

Comment: @Visko: AFAIK, Visual Studio won't accept it either, assuming you are compiling as C, not as C++. And your question is tagged C.

Comment: @Visko: I believe it's related to this entry in the C FAQ: http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html , although it's not identical and this *particular* case should be fine.

Comment: @Visko: you have to distinguish different versions of norms for C. For C99 the initializer has you gave it is no good, you'd have to write { 0 }. But // for comments is allowed, there. Best is probably to tell the compiler which norm you want to follow and then to stick to it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good solution to this problem - I usually just comment out the `const` qualifier on the function parameter to show that it should ideally be const but that we also want to compile without warnings, i.e.

```
int getVersion(/* const */ char params[MAX_PARAM_LEN][MAX_LINE_LEN],
               const char* tagName );
```

Comment: But then if you pass a `const char[][MAX_LINE_LEN]` to it, you'll get a warning! Isn't there any type that can take both `char [][N]` and `const char [][N]` without warning?

Comment: @Shabhaz: if you find a way then please let me know - with C it seems you have to pick one (const or non-const) and then be prepared to cast when passing the "wrong" type. Usually you will be passing non-const arrays (in my experience at least), hence the above recommendation.

Comment: Yeah, it is kind of annoying. Anyway, I'm fine without `const`. It's kind of useless anyway

Comment: `const` can be useful for catching logic bugs and potentially for compiler optimisations too - but in this case it's probably more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo((char const (*)[MAX_LINE_LEN] params);
```

works but is not very practical and could be dangerous (it accepts *any* pointer).

A more robust way would be:

```
foo((char const(*)[MAX_LINE_LEN])(char const*const){ &params[0][0] });
```

You can automate this "casting" using the macro P99_ACALL, see http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/const-and-arrays/ for more details.